# Using mongorestore to insert many documents into a temp collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mongodb, bson

I have an array of objects.

```
const arr = [
  {
    name: 'somename',
    age: 25,
  },
  {
    name: 'othername',
    age: 15,
  },
]
```

When I update my collection like so:

```
MyCollection.insertMany(arr);
```

it works properly. The collection has 2 Objects corresponding to the `arr` variable.

What I want to do is also store this data to a temp collection. As so:

```
const fileName = '/tmp/some_data.bson';
const data = BSON.serialize(arr); //arr from above
await fs.writeFile(fileName, data);
await child_process.exec(`mongorestore --drop -d my-db -c my_collection_temp ${fileName}`);
```

This works, but the `temp` collection only contains 1 object (instead of 2) and that 1 object has 2 fields which in turn have 2 fields each.

Sort of looks like this:

Main Collection:

```
Object1 { name: 'somename', age: 25 }
Object2 { name: 'someothername', age: 15 }
```

Temp Collection:

```
Object 1 {

  0: {
    name: 'somename', age: 25
  }
  1: {
    name: 'someothername', age: 15
  }

}
```

I get that when I execute `mongorestore --drop -d my-db -c my_collection_temp ${fileName}` it just dumps the Buffer into the collection but I need a way to omit this and spread the object as in the main collection.

In other words I guess I want to simulate `insertMany` through `mongorestore`

Any help is appreciated,

Answer (score 3):

When you call `BSON.serialize(arr)` you are serializing an array into a single BSON object.

Use bsondump to compare the file generated that way with the file generated using mongodump to export that collection.

The file format that mongorestore expects is a series of serialized BSON documents.

A bson file containing the 2 documents in your post would look like this:

```
00000000: 3600 0000 075f 6964 005e 4354 a93f 9947  6...._id.^CT.?.G
00000010: 050e 9bfc 0802 6e61 6d65 0009 0000 0073  ......name.....s
00000020: 6f6d 656e 616d 6500 0161 6765 0000 0000  omename..age....
00000030: 0000 0039 4000 3700 0000 075f 6964 005e  ...9@.7...._id.^
00000040: 4354 a93f 9947 050e 9bfc 0902 6e61 6d65  CT.?.G......name
00000050: 000a 0000 006f 7468 6572 6e61 6d65 0001  .....othername..
00000060: 6167 6500 0000 0000 0000 2e40 00         age........@.
```

Note that the first document begins at byte 0 with its size, and extends through byte 0x35.

The second document begins immediately at byte 0x36 with its size, and extends to the end of the file at bytes 0x6c.

To generate this file, you would need to call BSON.serialize on each document in turn, and append the bytes to the output file.